# Mysterious indexOutOfBoundsException involving a measureLimit in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception

My code works perfectly 99% of the time, but if I mash the keyboard long enough, I can sometimes get it to throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception. I can't tell you exactly how to reproduce it, because I can't reproduce it myself without literal minutes of keyboard mashing.

The bounds match the character limits on my different editTexts, but I can't work out what is causing an operation to try to do something outside of bounds.

The error has been triggered (indirectly) by the pushDigitToNextEditText, moveCursorIfNecessary, and pushDigitToFront methods, but it has also occurred with none of my code on the stacktrace, just android source code. (How is that possible?)

I've been able to find very little about this particular kind of outOfBounds exception, and I'm just about ready to give up. I can't believe an actual user would abuse the edit text boxes the way I have to to get it to throw the error, but who knows?

For the same reason I can't tell you how to reproduce it, I don't know what the minimum amount of code necessary is. So here's all of it. I added one of the stack traces, but I can give you more. I have lots.

```
package com.example.phonenumberdemo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.EditText
import com.example.phonenumberdemo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setUpPhoneEditTexts()
    }

    private var digitDeletedFlag = false
    private var userIsNotMakingChanges = false
    private var prevEditText1CursorPosition: Int? = null
    private var prevEditText2CursorPosition: Int? = null

    private fun setUpPhoneEditTexts() {
        phoneEditText1.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                if (userIsNotMakingChanges) {
                    return
                }
                if (phoneEditText1.text.length == 3) {
                    val lastDigit = chopOffLastDigit(1)
                    pushDigitToNextEditText(lastDigit, 2)
                    moveCursorIfNecessary(1)
                }
                if (digitDeletedFlag) {
                    pullDigitFromNextEditText(1)
                    digitDeletedFlag = false
                }
                prevEditText1CursorPosition = null
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                if (p3 < p2 && !userIsNotMakingChanges) {
                    digitDeletedFlag = true
                }
                prevEditText1CursorPosition = phoneEditText1.selectionStart
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
        })

        phoneEditText2.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                if (userIsNotMakingChanges) {
                    return
                }
                if (phoneEditText2.selectionEnd == 0) {
                    moveCursorBackTo(1)
                }
                if (phoneEditText2.text.length == 4) {
                    val lastDigit = chopOffLastDigit(2)
                    pushDigitToNextEditText(lastDigit, 3)
                    moveCursorIfNecessary(2)
                }
                if (digitDeletedFlag) {
                    pullDigitFromNextEditText(2)
                    digitDeletedFlag = false
                }
                prevEditText2CursorPosition = null
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                if (p3 < p2 && !userIsNotMakingChanges) {
                    digitDeletedFlag = true
                }
                prevEditText2CursorPosition = phoneEditText2.selectionStart
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
        })

        phoneEditText3.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                if (userIsNotMakingChanges) {
                    return
                }
                if (phoneEditText3.selectionEnd == 0) {
                    moveCursorBackTo(2)
                }
                if (phoneEditText3.text.length == 5) {
                    chopOffLastDigit(3)
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
        })
    }

    private fun chopOffLastDigit(editTextNum: Int): Char {
        val editText = getEditText(editTextNum)
        val maxLength = getMaxLength(editTextNum)
        val lastDigit = editText.text[maxLength]

        userIsNotMakingChanges = true
        editText.text.delete(maxLength, maxLength + 1)
        userIsNotMakingChanges = false

        return lastDigit
    }

    private fun pushDigitToNextEditText(digit: Char, nextEditTextNum: Int) {
        val nextEditText = getEditText(nextEditTextNum)
        val nextNextEditTextNum = getNextEditTextNum(nextEditTextNum)
        val maxLength = getMaxLength(nextEditTextNum)

        userIsNotMakingChanges = true
        var bumpedDigit: Char? = null
        if (nextEditText.text.length == maxLength) {
            bumpedDigit = nextEditText.text[maxLength - 1]
            nextEditText.text.delete(maxLength - 1, maxLength)
        }
        nextEditText.text.insert(0, digit.toString())
        if (bumpedDigit != null && nextNextEditTextNum != null) {
            pushDigitToNextEditText(bumpedDigit, nextNextEditTextNum)
        }
        userIsNotMakingChanges = false
    }

    private fun moveCursorBackTo(prevEditTextNum: Int) {
        val prevEditText = getEditText(prevEditTextNum)
        prevEditText.requestFocus()
        prevEditText.setSelection(prevEditText.length())
    }

    private fun moveCursorIfNecessary(editTextNum: Int) {
        if (editTextNum == 1 && prevEditText1CursorPosition!! > 1) {
            phoneEditText2.requestFocus()
            phoneEditText2.setSelection(prevEditText1CursorPosition!! - 2)
        } else if (editTextNum == 2 && prevEditText2CursorPosition!! > 2) {
            phoneEditText3.requestFocus()
            phoneEditText3.setSelection(prevEditText2CursorPosition!! - 3)
        }
    }

    private fun pullDigitFromNextEditText(editTextNum: Int) {
        val editText = getEditText(editTextNum)
        val maxLength = getMaxLength(editTextNum)
        val nextEditTextNum = getNextEditTextNum(editTextNum)
        val nextEditText = getNextEditText(editTextNum)

        if (editText.text.length != maxLength - 1) {
            return
        }
        if (nextEditText?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        userIsNotMakingChanges = true
        val pulledDigit = nextEditText!!.text[0]
        editText.text.append(pulledDigit)
        if (editText.selectionEnd == editText.text.length) {
            editText.setSelection(editText.selectionEnd - 1)
        }
        nextEditText.text.delete(0, 1)
        nextEditText.setText(nextEditText.text.toString())
        pullDigitFromNextEditText(nextEditTextNum!!)
        userIsNotMakingChanges = false
    }

    private fun getEditText(editTextNum: Int): EditText {
        return when (editTextNum) {
            1 -> phoneEditText1
            2 -> phoneEditText2
            3 -> phoneEditText3
            else -> error("invalid editTextNum")
        }
    }

    private fun getMaxLength(editTextNum: Int): Int {
        return when (editTextNum) {
            1 -> 2
            2 -> 3
            3 -> 4
            else -> error("invalid editTextNum")
        }
    }

    private fun getNextEditTextNum(editTextNum: Int): Int? {
        return when (editTextNum) {
            1 -> 2
            2 -> 3
            3 -> null
            else -> error("invalid editTextNum")
        }
    }

    private fun getNextEditText(editTextNum: Int): EditText? {
        return when (editTextNum) {
            1 -> phoneEditText2
            2 -> phoneEditText3
            3 -> null
            else -> error("invalid editTextNum")
        }
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter your phone number to create an account or to log in."
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" android:textSize="24sp" android:id="@+id/text_block"/>


        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phoneTextView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="(5"
                android:textSize="32sp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/phoneEditText1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_block"/>
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneEditText1"
                android:layout_width="43sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phoneTextView1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/phoneTextView1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneTextView1" android:textSize="32sp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/phoneTextView2"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phoneTextView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text=")"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phoneEditText1"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneTextView1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/phoneTextView1" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/phoneEditText2"/>
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneEditText2"
                android:layout_width="63sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:ems="10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phoneTextView2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneTextView1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/phoneTextView1" android:textSize="32sp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/phoneTextView3"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phoneTextView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="-"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phoneEditText2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneTextView1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/phoneTextView1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="32sp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/phoneEditText3"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneEditText3"
                android:layout_width="84sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:ems="10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phoneTextView3"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneTextView1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/phoneTextView1" android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Stack trace

```
2020-01-07 20:56:27.344 16142-16142/com.example.phonenumberdemo E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: measureLimit (4) is out of start (0) and limit (3) bounds
        at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1106)
        at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:528)
        at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:326)
        at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:1184)
        at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:1162)
        at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:1133)
        at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:1123)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionHandleView.getHorizontal(Editor.java:5562)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionHandleView.getHorizontal(Editor.java:5553)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.getCursorHorizontalPosition(Editor.java:4706)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.positionAtCursorOffset(Editor.java:4685)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionHandleView.positionAtCursorOffset(Editor.java:5466)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.show(Editor.java:4596)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.initHandles(Editor.java:5788)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.show(Editor.java:5760)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.enterDrag(Editor.java:5800)
        at android.widget.Editor.selectCurrentWordAndStartDrag(Editor.java:2187)
        at android.widget.Editor.access$7800(Editor.java:144)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:5848)
        at android.widget.Editor.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:1475)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:10056)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
2020-01-07 20:56:27.344 16142-16142/com.example.phonenumberdemo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-01-07 20:56:27.351 16142-16142/com.example.phonenumberdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.phonenumberdemo, PID: 16142
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: measureLimit (4) is out of start (0) and limit (3) bounds
        at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1106)
        at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:528)
        at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:326)
        at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:1184)
        at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:1162)
        at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:1133)
        at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:1123)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionHandleView.getHorizontal(Editor.java:5562)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionHandleView.getHorizontal(Editor.java:5553)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.getCursorHorizontalPosition(Editor.java:4706)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.positionAtCursorOffset(Editor.java:4685)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionHandleView.positionAtCursorOffset(Editor.java:5466)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.show(Editor.java:4596)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.initHandles(Editor.java:5788)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.show(Editor.java:5760)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.enterDrag(Editor.java:5800)
        at android.widget.Editor.selectCurrentWordAndStartDrag(Editor.java:2187)
        at android.widget.Editor.access$7800(Editor.java:144)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:5848)
        at android.widget.Editor.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:1475)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:10056)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
2020-01-07 20:56:27.351 16142-16142/com.example.phonenumberdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2020-01-07 20:56:26.272 16142-16166/com.example.phonenumberdemo D/TextClassifierService: No configured system TextClassifierService
2020-01-07 20:56:27.373 16142-16142/com.example.phonenumberdemo I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16142 SIG: 9
```

Comment: While you're not using Xamarin, this may demonstrate a problem with Android: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7534#issuecomment-534507925

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but did you end up finding a solution? I'm running into the same problem and have no idea why.

Comment: No, I didn't. If you do, please let me know! @AndrewHeschl

Comment: @AnnaliseTarhan I'm not sure this is relevant to your post, but I fixed my problem by adding runOnUiThread around my code editing the EditText content. I was multi threading, and for some reason it never threw an early error about thread accessing ui. My error message is identical to yours, so I hope this can give you some direction, even though it doesn't seem that you're multi-threading.